# Can't Sign In to Azure Subscription Services via Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2005, server-explorer

I am trying to connect to my Azure Subscription (MSDN Premium) through Visual Studio 2013. When I sign in (using the same account that is used for the Management Portal) I get the following error, "An error occurred during the sign in process: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." I've seen a few people run into a similar, but not the same situation. Some suggest resetting IE security settings to default. I've tried this with no success. Others suggest shortening the PATH environment variable. The variable on this machine is only about 600 characters in length (so shouldn't be an issue). I've also restarted the machine. Nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

EXTRA INFORMATION: I just checked my Live account activity log and it shows a successful sign in to the Live account so it seems that the issue is specifically within visual studio.

Comment: One of the workaround, you can use "traditional" management certificate to authenticate in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just created a certificate and uploaded to the azure portal. This helped me move one step closer... now, the Azure item in server explorer shows 1 subscription, but I still can't sign in (same error). Also, when I try to refresh App Service (under Azure in server explorer), I get the following message, "Unable to get children of 'App Service' - Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation. This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.."

Comment: I've had numerous issues with the signing into Azure via VS over the past 1.5 years, most of the time VS crashes for me. I've had VS crash more times the last year than all prior years combined. I will say over the past few months it's gotten better. I've spent countless hours searching and trying various things, seemed for me getting rid of the certificates made things better

Comment: I would like to recommend contact MS. I met an issue in azure server explorer and after checked with azure support, (finally checked with azure dev team) we found it's because of a cloud service was deployed by very old SDK (1.x).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2013. I can also vouch that when I disabled FIPS on windows 8.1 things started working fine.